# Variable arguments function and method chaining with string

Tags: c++

I'm working on a function that creates API query statements.

There is a condition that I should not use string in the main function. If so, the intention of method chaining is diluted. The desired syntax must be written through modifications within the company class.

The information for understanding was as above, and more details are as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

class Meta {
public:
    string meta = "meta=";

    string tokens() {
        return meta + "tokens&type=";
    }
    template<typename String>
    string tokens(String arg) {
        string p = arg;
        return p;
    }
    template<typename String, typename ... Strings>
    string tokens(String arg, Strings ... args) {
        string p1 = arg;
        string p2 = tokens(args...);
        return tokens() + p1 + "|" + p2;
    }
};

int main() {
    Meta meta;
    cout << meta.tokens("logintoken", "write", "patrol");
    return 0;
}
```

This is part of the Wikipedia Action API, which is a procedure to increase the readability of code at the programmer level, which simply implements query statements without creating special symbols for query statements by writing functions of objects with on-points through method chaining.
It should be the output like this:

```
meta=tokens&type=logintoken|write|patrol
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Is C++11 almost 13 years old strictly limited?

Comment: *"The output should be..."* What is the current output?

Comment: Also where are all the `#include`s. This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Comment: @273K No, it's not limited to C++11. Sorry for my clumsy.

Comment: @JaMiT I've added a few explanations. I've divided it into two parts, one with easy code to help understand, and the other with code about how it's actually used. Please let me know if you have any additional fixes for other programmers' reference.

Comment: I don't think the first part is needed. It is formally equivalent to the second part and not really much easier to understand.

Comment: @Weijun Zhou I revised the code once again by referring to your advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the question here? I don't understand the ask at all.

Comment: @kiner_shah I answered  for your reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that? Only the `Company` is modified.
https://godbolt.org/z/r7q6jEq5G

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

class Company {
  template <typename T>
  string name1(T arg) {
    return arg;
  }

  template <typename T, typename... Ts>
  string name1(T arg, Ts... args) {
    return std::string(arg) + ", " + name1(args...);
  }

 public:
  string name() { return "In the companies, there are "; }

  template <typename... Ts>
  string name(Ts... args) {
    return name() + name1(args...);
  }
};

int main() {
  Company company;
  cout << company.name("StackOverFlow", "EA", "Xerox", "YouTube");
  return 0;
}

// In the companies, there are StackOverFlow, EA, Xerox, YouTube
```

Since C++17, [Fold epression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) is useful.
https://godbolt.org/z/13hf8a19e

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

class Company {
  template <typename T, typename... Ts>
  string name1(T arg, Ts... args) {
    return arg + (... + (", " + std::string(args)));
  }

 public:
  string name() { return "In the companies, there are "; }

  template <typename... Ts>
  string name(Ts... args) {
    return name() + name1(args...);
  }
};

int main() {
  Company company;
  cout << company.name("StackOverFlow", "EA", "Xerox", "YouTube");
  return 0;
}
```

The commas make the code a bit longer.

Comment: Sorry to ask like this, but I have faced into the error, which triggers when I use only one parameter: a unary fold expression over '+' must have a non-empty expansion, Compiler error C7516. Could I ask you of it?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also handle if there is one factor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

class Meta {
    template <typename String>
    string tokens1(String arg) {
        return arg;
    }

    template <typename String, typename... Strings>
    string tokens1(String arg, Strings... args) {
        return arg + (... + ("|" + std::string(args)));
    }

public:
    string tokens() {
        return "https://ko.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&type=";
    }

    template <typename... Strings>
    string tokens(Strings... args) {
        return tokens() + tokens1(args...);
    }
};

int main() {
    Meta company;
    cout << company.tokens("logintoken");
    return 0;
}
```